# Send Hex from php to device using socket_sendto

Tags: c#, php, sockets, hex

I have spent days trying to figure this out. I have a GPS tracker device that communicates using UDP protocol.
And I have a hex string I need to send to this tracker:
"0d0a2a4b5700440002000000000000002a4b572c4e5230394230353330342c3030372c3034333133392c3023000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d0a"
If I send this string using c#, the device replies back. C# Code:

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        int NumberChars = hex.Length / 2;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars];
        using (var sr = new StringReader(hex))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i++)
                bytes[i] =
                  Convert.ToByte(new string(new char[2] { (char)sr.Read(), (char)sr.Read() }), 16);
        }
        return bytes;
    }



// Send Message to tracker
         public static void send(string ip, string port, string msg)
            {
                Byte[] sendBytes = StringToByteArray(msg);
                try
                {
                    IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), int.Parse(port));
                    UDPreceiver.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, ipEndPoint);
                    Program.form1.addlog("Sent: " + ByteArrayToString(sendBytes) + " - to " + ip + " on port: " + port);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "error");
                }
            }
```

Now If I try to send the same hex string from PHP. The device does not respond, here's the php code:

```
// Function send
    function send($ip,$port,$message){
        $socket_bytes = false;
        try {
            // Prepare message
            $strlen = strlen($message);
            $message = hex2bin(strtoupper($message));
            // Send Packet
            if(!($this->socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP))){
                die('msg,could not create socket');
            }
            $socket_bytes = socket_sendto($this->socket, $message, $strlen, 0, $ip, $port);
            socket_close($this->socket);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            return false;
        }
        return $socket_bytes;
    }
```

I have exhausted my self trying to figure out how to send this. Please any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but

strlen($message) != strlen(hex2bin(strtoupper($message)));

```
$message = 'ABCD';
echo strlen($message); //==4
echo "\n";
echo strlen(hex2bin(strtoupper($message))); //==2
```

Comment: I did try strlen($message) with no avail.